# NULL Pointer Problem?

Tags: c++, null, pointers

```
void Insert(AVLnode * & root, string X)
{
    if ( root == NULL)
    {
        root = GetNode(X);
    }
    else if ( root->info > X )
    {
        Insert(root->left,X);
        if ( height(root->left) - height(root->right) == 2 )
            if ( X < root->left->info )
                RotateRR(root);
            else
                RotateLR(root);
    }
    else if ( root->info < X )
    {
        Insert(root->right,X);
        if ( height(root->right) - height(root->left) == 2 )
            if ( X > root->right->info )
                RotateRR(root);
            else
                RotateLR(root);
    }
    root->height = max( height(root->left), height(root->right) )+1;
}
AVLnode* find(AVLnode* root,string X)
{
    if (!root) return 0;
    if ( root->info == X )
        return root;
    else if (root->info < X)
        find(root->left,X);
    else if (root->info > X)
        find(root->right,X);
    return 0;   
}
int main(int argc,char* argv)
{
    AVLnode* Dic;
    Insert(Dic,"adf");
    return 0;
}
```

The first time in `Insert`, `root` is NULL but when I debug, it skips `root == null`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `AVLnode* Dic;` statement of `main()`. You are sending an uninitialized pointer to `insert()` from `main()`. It contains garbage values. Initialize it to `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

The first time it's not NULL. Variables do not auto-initialize to NULL or 0 in C++; they contain garbage (whatever the memory address they occupy contained before).

Replace `AVLnode* Dic;` with `AVLnode* Dic = NULL;` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

"The first time in Insert", in the code you give, `root` is a "random"-ish value, because you never initialize `Dic` -- so it may well happen to be NULL when you're running without a debugger and otherwise if you *are* using a debugger.  That's just a definite bug in your code, so add `= 0` before the `;` in the first line of `main`'s body.  After which, you may find more bugs (hard to say, since you don't show us `GetNode` or the `Rotate` thingies, even though you **do** show us the `find` function that's never ever called -- peculiar choice of code to show us, indeed).